# High boottime - Big gaps in dmesg

Tags: boot, dmesg

My system takes a very long time to boot.

systemd-analyze:

> Startup finished in 8.487s (kernel) + 3min 544ms (userspace) = 3min 9.032s

systemd-analyze blame:

> ```
>        10.451s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>        462ms lvm2-monitor.service
>        313ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
>        313ms plymouth-quit.service
>        229ms dev-sda1.device
>        112ms accounts-daemon.service
>        104ms ModemManager.service
>         92ms ufw.service
>         81ms grub-common.service
>         66ms systemd-hostnamed.service
>         65ms systemd-logind.service
>         65ms thermald.service
>         56ms upower.service
>         56ms avahi-daemon.service
>         54ms NetworkManager.service
>         54ms loadcpufreq.service
>         43ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
>         42ms virtualbox-guest-utils.service
>         41ms virtualbox.service
>         39ms console-setup.service
>         37ms irqbalance.service
>         36ms keyboard-setup.service
>         35ms ondemand.service
> ```

Gap 1 in dmesg

> ```
>  [    8.863159] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1469
>  [    8.864323] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd failed with error -2
>  [    8.864325] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd not found
>  [    8.997167] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
>  [    8.997895] wl 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
>  [   98.812110] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
>  [   98.812113] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
>  [   98.812116] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
>  [   98.815767] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
> ```

Gap 2

> ```
>  [   99.048746] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
>  [   99.280376] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
>  [   99.285219] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
>  [  109.372035] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
>  [  109.387960] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3997683369 Hz
>  [  109.387961] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.24_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)
> ```

Gap 3

> ```
> [  109.390945] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
> [  109.393473] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
> [  109.396341] VBoxPciLinuxInit
> [  109.397795] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
> [  118.560770] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: BE
> [  118.560772] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
> [  118.560773] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
> [  118.560774] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> [  118.560776] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
> [  118.560776] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
> [  118.560777] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
> [  118.560778] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
> [  125.752904] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
> [  125.752909] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
> [  125.752912] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
> ```

Gap 4

> ```
> [  126.399364] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
> [  191.260055] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=6c:71:d9:f1:e3:f8:5c:35:3b:93:57:77:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=25083 PROTO=2
> ```

Other info:
[Hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqFZs.png)

I recently had a dualboot setup with win10. My SSD was split up in 2 partitions (sda1 had win10 & sda2 had Linux Mint). I deleted sda1, copied the sda2 partition to sda1 & resized sda1 to incorporate the total disk & recreated a swap partition, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mik4C.png)

I'm quite new to linux and have tried various solutions like setting a lower timeout on networkmanager (it used to take 30s, now it times out at 10)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to augment boot time significantly (22.242s). The UUID for my swap partition was incorrect in /etc/crypttab.